# How to declare an icon to show in the editor dialog?

Tags: macros, icons, godot, gdscript

At [the very first page of the reference manual of GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html) there is a *learn GDscript in x minutes* with a line of code which seems to be a macro `@icon("path/to.png")` but that does not work on the latest version of Godot (v 3.3.stable.mono.official):

---

### @icon minimal example

```
class_name Player

extends KinematicBody2D

@icon("res://icon.png")

func _ready() -> void:
    pass
```

---

#### error

```
Parser Error: Parse error: Unexpected '@'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading documentation for Godot 4.0 (look in the url, you want "stable" not "latest"). See also [GDScript progress report: New GDScript is now merged](https://godotengine.org/article/gdscript-progress-report-new-gdscript-now-merged).

In Godot 3.x to specify an script icon you do it in the `class_name` statement, like this:

```
class_name Player, "res://icon.png"
```

See [Register scripts as classes](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html?highlight=class_name#register-scripts-as-classes).